# JQuery validation data exist in table with space

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want if a data have already existed in record it will be disabled my save button, so far I manage to do that, but if the data contain **space** it didn't work, I believe it is because sending data through JQuery will change the **space** into **%20** how to overcome this? Below is my code

Here is my JQuery

```
<!-- Unique Data Validation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#kProject').bind('keyup change',function(){
    var check1=0;
    var name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'project/cekData/master_kategori_project/kategori_project/'+name,
      data:{send:true},
      success:function(data){
        if(data==1){
          $('#report1').text('');
          $('.btn_save').prop('disabled',false);
          check1=1;
        }else{
          $('#report1').text('Project Exist');
          $('.btn_save').prop('disabled',true);
          check1=0;
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
</script>
<!-- End Unique Data Validation -->
```

and this is my controller

```
public function cekData($table, $field, $data){
    $match = $this->project_m->read($table, array($field=>$data), null, null);
    if($match->num_rows() > 0){
        $report = 2;// exist
    }else{
        $report = 1;//not exist
    }
    echo $report;
}
```

and this is my model

```
public function read($table, $cond, $ordField, $ordType){
    if($cond!=null){
        $this->db->where($cond);
    }
    if($ordField!=null){
        $this->db->order_by($ordField, $ordType);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    return $query;
}
```

example my table looks like below, there is no **%20** in my table so when jQuery send the data the data would have something like `Jalan%20Tol` of course `Jalan%20Tol` doesn't exist in my table, it only exist `Jalan Tol`

[image]

Comment: so the %20 is in the success `data` variable?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM yes when i send data using JQuery if the `data` have a **space** like `This Is Data` the data would change the **space** into `This%20Is%20Data`

Comment: You are disabling the `save` button based on the value of `data` variable. What you are sending through ajax is the `name` and  response from ajax call is stored in `data`. You are checking for `data==1` in if statement and if not equal to `1` then you are disabling the button. Couldn't understand the problem. What is the response you are getting when you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: my problem is, the data send a url with **%20**, i want to make that **%20** disappear check out my edit

Comment: In JavaScript you can decode the URI using `decodeURI(data)`.

Comment: ah yes i just read about that, the problem is which part i need to place that `decoreURI`? i've already try some possibility but it isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built-in function for things like that
try it that way

```
public function cekData($table, $field, $data){
    $data = urldecode($data);
    $match = $this->project_m->read($table, array($field=>$data), null, null);
    if($match->num_rows() > 0){
        $report = 2;// exist
    }else{
        $report = 1;//not exist
    }
    echo $report;
}
```

Comment: i just have an hectic week, so i just be able to try this code today and yes it work so simple yet so effective, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not about the jQuery but the controller you are using. In PHP, I used many times `%20` and `data.serialize()` function which puts `20%` as well instead of `spaces` but never got a problem. Your controller doesn't recognize `20%` as `space`. So you need to change `20%` with a value which your controller will recognize as `space`.